# How do I view what programming languages are used in a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

Where in the GitHub repo interface do I go to find what programming langauge(s) are being used?

[The Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/) provides this information but does not actually explain how to access it.

> The files and directories within a repository determine the languages that make up the repository. You can view a repository's languages to get a quick overview of the repository.

Answer (score 5):

The languages have been moved underneath the contributors. In the desktop view, that's at the bottom of the right column; in the mobile view, it's all the way at the bottom of the page.

[image: Desktop view, showing the languages at the bottom of the right column]

Comment: Is there a way to expand out the 'other' category?